# What does one need to give, for liberation?

Tags: personal-practice, nirvana

A twofold question for the sake to become even one.

General theoretical, general practical and personal answers of reflection (and generously let others have part of it) are suitable. Or even incl. all the views on it, to give a broad spectrum to grasp.

(Liberation here means the highest goal a living being can archive: end of suffering and stress)

Answer (score 3):

All you have to give up are your preconceptions.  All you need to give is your trust in the process.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64760/discussion-on-answer-by-xxxx-what-does-one-need-to-give-for-liberation).

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean what you need to give up in order to become free from suffering?

[Dhammapada 221](http://www.tipitaka.net/tipitaka/dhp/verseload.php?verse=221) says:

> Give up anger, abandon conceit, overcome all fetters. Ills of life
>   (dukkha) do not befall one who does not cling to mind and body and is
>   free from moral defilements.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64762/discussion-on-answer-by-ruben2020-what-does-one-need-to-give-for-liberation).

Answer (score 0):

You don't give in any thing to Nibbana but you realise Nibbana.
Once you realise Nibbana you release from gross factors to subtle factors gradually and develop Bodhiakkhiyadharma.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodhipakkhiy%C4%81dhamm%C4%81

========

Then Ven. Sariputta went to the Blessed One and, on arrival, bowed down to him and sat to one side. As he was sitting there, the Blessed One said to him, "Sariputta, how many are the strengths of a monk whose effluents are ended, endowed with which he affirms the ending of the effluents (thus): 'The effluents are ended in me'?"

"Eight, lord, are the strengths of a monk whose effluents are ended, endowed with which he affirms the ending of the effluents (thus): 'The effluents are ended in me.' Which eight?

http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an08/an08.028.than.html

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64763/discussion-on-answer-by-sarathw-what-does-one-need-to-give-for-liberation).

Answer (score 0):

> "What does one need to give, for liberation?"

His self.

Once the self is given, it is realised that nothing is ever given nor taken.

Giving or taking are just mere concepts ... illusions ... not truth.

It is within this realisation of the truth that liberation is achieved.

But again ...

Achieving or not achieving are just mere concepts ... illusions ... not truth.

It is within this realisation of the truth that liberation is achieved.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64815/discussion-on-answer-by-beginner-what-does-one-need-to-give-for-liberation).

Answer (score 0):

Friendliness. Compassion. Joy for others. Equanimity

Cultivate these states within yourself and send the feeling out to all beings. Anything experienced from developing these skilful states, give.